# Collapsing/expanding expandable list view changes the toggle of random child in checkedtextview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I am able to implement checkedtextview in expandablelistview. But when I check certain child item , some child item of other parent gets selected as well . I am unable to figure out why am I facing such problem? Any one faced similar situation ? Thanks for help in advance.

EDIT :

As suggested I created boolean multidimensional array in customadapter:       `

```
Boolean[][] categoryx = new Boolean` [5][5];
```

There is getchildView method in custom adapter :

```
 @Override
      public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
          boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          System.out.print(groupPosition);
          System.out.println(childPosition);
        final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        CheckedTextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
        }
        text = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_textView1);
        text.setText(children);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              ((CheckedTextView )v).toggle();
          }
        });
        return convertView;
      }
```

But I am confused in which method should I toggle my values using accessed childposition.

EDIT 2 : My custom adapter where I am trying to save state :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyCategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

      private SparseArray<Groupx> groups;
      public LayoutInflater inflater;
      public Activity activity;
      Boolean[][] categoryx = new Boolean [5][5];

      public MyCategoryAdapter(Activity act, SparseArray<Groupx> groups) {
        activity = act;
        this.groups = groups;
        inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
      }

      @Override
      public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
          boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          System.out.print(groupPosition);
          System.out.println(childPosition);
        final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        CheckedTextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
        }
        text = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_textView1);
        text.setText(children);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              //Integer lol = (Integer) v.getTag();
              ((CheckedTextView )v).toggle();
          }
        });
        return convertView;
      }

      @Override
      public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).children.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
      }

      @Override
      public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
      }

      @Override
      public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
      }

      @Override
      public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
      }

      @Override
      public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
        }
        Groupx group = (Groupx) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(group.stringx.toString());
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that regularly arises due to the misunderstanding of the ListView row recycling.

The thing is, you are only keeping the checked attribute in your view. Now, `ListView`s reuse cells that disappear from the screen for saving memory, and so, once a row is checked, another one will appear checked as well, once the original one has been recycled.

To circumvent this, you will have to save the checked state in your `ListView`'s data source, and set the appropriate checked value in your `ListView` adapter.

Comment: Will read and definitely try above tip , thanks for your time

Comment: exactly where should I toggle my multidimensional boolean array ,I am unable to change its value at setOnClickListener . please see the above edit for details

Comment: I did it using multidimensional boolean array , there is no other alternative it seems , but How can I utilise that boolean inside my custom adapter to be used further in my activity to figure out what all values have been selected . check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680297/how-to-access-checked-child-in-expandablelistview-with-checkedtextview

Answer (score 0):

Set singlechoicemode:true in xml.

Comment: This would prevent the user from selecting multiple rows, but the problem seems to be that rows appear to get checked without the user clicking them.

Comment: and singlechoicemode is not even an option provided by checkedtextview

Comment: Try by adding selectors item in drawable... so that you can fix state enabled to true.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Override methods from BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
 //define a condition here to differentiate between your child views.
}

public int getChildTypeCount() {
 return 2; <-- this is the number of views for your child
}
```

Hope this will help.